# Как установить LAMP и NGINX на WSL2?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lamp, wsl, wsl2

можно ли установить на WSL2 (Ubuntu) установить LAMP + NGINX ? А также использовать графическую оболочку. Чтобы не ставить второй операционной системой Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

lamp и nginx ставятся без каких-либо проблем.

GUI доступен для майской сборки windows 10 или выше.
https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#pre-requisites